# Where is this style coming from on my page?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a screenshot here of Chrome Developer Tools

[image]

Normally the style clearly comes from a particular css file (in the screenshot, datepicker.css). I'm trying to alter (very top of screenshot)

```
element.style {
  display: block;
  top: 452px
  left: 7.6875px;
}
```

but can't find it (having searched all my CSS files). Where is this style coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element.style` means the `style` property/attribute on the element itself – inline styles.